# Create short int memory allocation in C

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

Here `short int` memory is allocated but in my **64 bit** computer it return size 4 instead of 2 ? But How I should create `short int` memory allocation and how display it?

```
int *ptr;
ptr = (int * ) malloc(sizeof(short int));
*ptr = 7;
printf("%d\n", sizeof(*ptr)); // It returns 4 instead of 2
```

Comment: Note that you really cannot tell the size of the allocation after a call to malloc. Even if you did `malloc(1000)` the value for `sizeof(*ptr)` would still be the same (and not 1000).

Answer (score 2):

You should be using a pointer to `short`.

```c
short *ptr;
ptr = malloc(sizeof(short));
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(*ptr));
```

Note: a common idiom when allocating memory is to use `*ptr` as the expression for `sizeof` to use as that will give the correct number of bytes that should be allocated for a variable of this type.

```c
short *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(*ptr));
```